# I need to apply single sign on for Alfresco Community 4.0 , could somebody give me some instruction or steps?

Tags: java, alfresco

I have Alfresco community v4.0 installed on my windows server 2003. I configured LDAP in alfresco , Now I need to configure single sign on. So could anybody give me some details regarding that , that would be very helpful for me ?

Comment: What Single Sign-On system are you planning to use? How much of that system is already installed and configured?

Comment: Currently I have alfrescoNtlm and ldap configured in Alfresco.I dont know that much about single sign on. Could you provide me some detailed information about sso ?

Answer (score 1):

it depends on your system configuration (LDAP, AD, external systems like kerberos etc), but globally, it should be like this:
go to `alfresco.global.properties` file in your `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension` directory (if you don't have a file like that there, simply create it.
then add the following lines (here depends on how the userNameFormat is passed by your LDAP to the application):

```
ntlm.authentication.sso.enabled=true

authentication.chain=passthru1:passthru,alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm,ldap1:ldap-ad

passthru.authentication.useLocalServer=false
passthru.authentication.domain=yourdomain.local
passthru.authentication.servers=domainControllerResolvedHostname

ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=%s
ldap.authentication.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://yourdomain:port
ldap.authentication.active=false
ldap.authentication.java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory

ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=ou\=users,ou=yourGroup,dc=mainGroup,dc=local
ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=ou\=users,ou=yourGroup,dc=mainGroup,dc=local
ldap.synchronization.userIdAttributeName=sAMAccountName
```

a couple of notes:

- userNameFormat = here it depends if your users are logging with their active directory username or with the extension @yourdomain (example: %s = johnDoe or johnDoe@yourdomain.local)
- url = you should put there your Active Directory server (IP or resolved hostname), and the port used (usually 389)

you should look here for some more info:
[Alfresco Docs Passthru](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/tasks/auth-example-passthu.html)